# Synonymize [coingecko-api] to [coingecko]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

It seems a user has  changed two questions on [coingecko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coingecko) to [coingecko-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coingecko-api). This change seems unnecessary. They both refer to the same api. Requesting that they be made synonyms.

Comment: Well, those edits are obviously bad and we should definitely merge the tags.  That said, since we're discussing it...what should the final tag name be?  Is the coingecko tag attracting off-topic questions that a -api name would clarify?  Should we just use the -api name anyway?  Thoughts?

Comment: @RyanM I think it was Cody who said, Every tag is somehow related to a api one way or another and we shouldn't be adding a api suffix to  every tag(I couldn't find that answer/quote now though). I don't think it's necessary to add the suffix. I sampled the questions and none are blatantly offtopic. Even if they are(in the future), adding a `-api`  suffix to a tag would do little, if anything to change that. [coingecko] is the best choice, given current scenario.

Comment: Good point.  [coingecko] it is.  Done.